# How do I calculate a new column in Pandas based a on trignometric function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following columns (sin and cos of a angle)

```
                SWD         CWD
2013-12-06  -0.394097   -0.350099
2013-12-07  -0.388295   -0.271105
2013-12-08  -0.391894   -0.202537
2013-12-09  -0.388662   -0.430063
2013-12-10  -0.396427   -0.433933
```

How can I create a new column with the arctan of the angle (atan(sin/cos)?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use numpy's `arctan`

```
In [42]:

df['ATAN'] = np.arctan(df['SWD']/df['CWD'])
df
Out[42]:
         Date       SWD       CWD      ATAN
0  2013-12-06 -0.394097 -0.350099  0.844451
1  2013-12-07 -0.388295 -0.271105  0.961284
2  2013-12-08 -0.391894 -0.202537  1.093787
3  2013-12-09 -0.388662 -0.430063  0.734874
4  2013-12-10 -0.396427 -0.433933  0.740260
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking that atan is really what you want, rather than [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) ([`arctan2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) in numpy).

Comment: Good point but arctan2 takes coordinate values, the OP has stated the values are angle values so I think arctan is the more appropriate function here I reckon

Comment: atan2 gives an angle though, it's just in a different range (and they do have sin and cos columns). At any rate, worth pointing it out incase it is what they want, and just didn't know about atan2.